# Contraction theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following sequence:

See image for the theorem where the x and y came from! [image]

$\{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$  Where $t_1=1/2$ and $t_{n+1}=\sqrt{(t_n+1)}$

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$
converges and determine the limit.

I have to use the contraction theorem.

Now i did the algebra and came to $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)}\sqrt{(y+1)}}c{|x-y|}$$ and now i am stuck i know the limit is either $x=1\pm $$\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$

How can we determine an interval and the number c so that f is a contraction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt {1+x}\;$. Take $r > 2$  and   let $J=[0,r]$.

For $x\in J$ we have $$
0<f(x)< 1+\frac {x}{2}\leq 1+\frac {r}{2}<r$$ so $f(x)\in J.$

Let $c=\frac {1}{2}$. For $x,y\in J$ with $x\ne y$ we have $$\frac {|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}=\frac {1}{\sqrt {1+x}\; +\sqrt {1+y}}\leq \frac {1}{2}=c<1.$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54855/discussion-on-answer-by-user254665-contraction-theorem). Pertinent information should be added to the post via n [edit].